# How to validate a Stream is valid UTF8 in c#

Tags: c#, utf-8

There are many questions that ask for detecting file encoding, which is tricky. I only need to know if the file contains only valid UTF8 sequences, thus being safe to treat as UTF8 (plain ASCII can be safely treated as UTF8)

The File comes in a form of a `Stream` from within `AspNetCore`.

I assume I will have to read the stream twice, first to check it doesn't contain any invalid UTF8 sequences, and second to actually process it further.

Comment: What does `treat as UTF8` mean? Almost all web sites and API responses are UTF8 (there may be some buggy, 20 year old device still serving something else). .NET Core's StreamReader will treat everything as UTF8 by default unless the stream starts with a BOM that says otherwise. A US-ASCII file is indistinguishable from UTF8 by definition. So yes, the only way to know if a file *can't* be treated as UTF8 is to look for any bytes that can't be parsed. You don't need to read the file twice either if you load it in memory.

Comment: A better question is why do you need to treat any stream as non-Unicode? Where would a non-Unicode stream come from? It would be better to *prevent* the non-Unicode data in the first place. An HTTP endpoint could read the `Content-Type` to detect the body's encoding so it doesn't have to guess what the encoding is

Comment: `UTF8Encoding` has a constructor with two `bool` parameters. The second one is `throwOnInvalidBytes`. `Encoding.UTF8` has that set to `false`. New up an instance with `true` for that parameter and pass that instance to the `StreamReader`. Let it throw an exception when a sequence of bytes is invalid in the UTF-8 encoding. Then you only have to read it once.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thats exactly what I'm trying to do. I have a Stream that may have non-utf8 data in it, I'd like to reject it in this case.

Comment: @madreflection I don't have a stream reader, I have a `Stream`. I can create a reader, call read on it until theres nothing left, and then rewind the stream (if it supports it, I have a feeling this one doesnt). I was hoping there would be a less laborious way to do this. The Stream itself is used further elsewhere.

Comment: So if you're reading it *twice*, how are you reading it once it's validated (i.e. the second time)?

Comment: @madreflection I convert the stream into Base64 (using CryptoStream) and write it into a database. That takes a `Stream`, not a `StreamReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment by @madreflection:

```cs
public static async Task<bool> IsValidUtf8(Stream stream)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding(true, true));
    try
    {
        await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (DecoderFallbackException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I was hoping I wouldn't have to read the stream twice, but that's not possible, but also undesired, as I need to make a decision before processing.

One thing that bothers me about this is that the whole stream is read into RAM, but CodeReview might be a better place to discuss that.